# Is there way to get removed steam games like this api api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v2/?

Tags: steam

This api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v2/
shows only public games. But removed games like this https://steamdb.info/app/24170/
doesn't showed from GetAppList

Any ideas how to get full game list with removed games?

Comment: I think the AppID is simply a number starting with 1 and counting up. It shouldn't be too hard to write a crawler that tries to see if a certain game exists whose number isn't on the official list.

Answer (score -1):

I found this one, called Steam Tracker: https://steam-tracker.com/api?action=GetAppList

It is not official, but worked.